# SQL Server 2012 - How does "Repeatable Read" isolation level work?

Tags: sql-server, transactions

I feel like I should know this, but I can't find anything that specifically outlines this, so here goes.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) for SQL Server describes REPEATABLE READ as:

> Specifies that statements cannot read data that has been modified but
>   not yet committed by other transactions and that no other transactions
>   can modify data that has been read by the current transaction until
>   the current transaction completes

This makes sense, but what actually *happens* when one of these situation arises? If, for example, Transaction A reads row 1, and then Transaction B attempts to update row 1, what happens? Does Transaction B wait until Transaction A has finished and then try again? Or is an exception thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`REPEATABLE READ` takes S-locks on all rows that have been read by query plan operators for the duration of the transaction. The answer to your question follows from that:

1. If the read comes first it S-locks the row and the write must wait.
2. If the write comes first the S-lock waits for the write to commit.

Under Hekaton it works differently because there are no locks.

Comment: Right, so it does *wait*, then? So Transaction A doesn't actually prevent Transaction B *making* it's update - it just makes it wait until Transaction A has finished before doing so?

Comment: It waits before making the write or read of that specific row. Isn't the answer clear that it waits?